Visualizing Time-Series Data with Heatmaps and 3D Surface Plots
I need to visualize different indices as a heatmap or image. The goal is to plot hours on the y-axis, dates on the x-axis, and intensity values for each day. The attached figure illustrates the desired output:

I aim to create a figure using pcolormesh, pcolor, imshow, or Seaborn's heatmap.
For context, KP > 40 indicates a storm, and DST < -30 also indicates a storm. An important date in the data is 2020/09/01, which corresponds to an earthquake.
Here's the approach I've tried so far:
X, Y = np.meshgrid(sw_indices.index.day, sw_indices.index.hour)
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
Z = griddata((sw_indices.index.day, sw_indices.index.hour), 
sw_indices.kp, (X, Y), method="nearest")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)

Context
The data being visualized in the described scenario is time series data concerning space weather indices, which track various environmental and astronomical measurements over time. The specific indices mentioned are:

kp: A planetary geomagnetic activity index, which measures geomagnetic storms. KP values above 40 typically indicate significant geomagnetic activity or storms.
dst: Another geomagnetic index, where values below -30 indicate geomagnetic storms.
ssn: Sunspot number, which is an index of the number of sunspots and groups of sunspots present on the surface of the sun.
f10.7: The solar radio flux at 10.7 cm (2800 MHz), which is a measurement of the solar emissions in the microwave range, and it's often used as a proxy for solar activity.

The visualization aims to present space weather conditions by plotting KP index values across different hours and days. In this heatmap, the KP index is used as an indicator of geomagnetic activity, with higher values signifying more intense geomagnetic storms. By setting up the axes with dates on the x-axis and hours on the y-axis, and by mapping KP index values to color intensity, the visualization provides an insightful look into how geomagnetic conditions fluctuate over time. This approach allows for easy identification of critical events, such as storms, by observing changes in color intensity across the grid.
The intended visualization method, such as using pcolormesh, pcolor, imshow, or Seaborn's heatmap, is apt for this kind of data as they can effectively show variations across two dimensions with color coding to represent the third dimension (intensity or magnitude of the indices). Other indices like dst, ssn, and f10.7 could potentially be visualized in a similar manner to track different types of environmental conditions or solar activity.
Data
Here's the link to the full data file: Google Drive Link
Here are excerpts from the data:
,year,doy,hr,kp,ssn,dst,f10_7
2020-08-02 00:00:00,YEAR,DOY,HR,1,2,3,4.0
2020-08-02 01:00:00,2020,215,0,3,15,18,74.9
2020-08-02 02:00:00,2020,215,1,3,15,16,74.9
2020-08-02 03:00:00,2020,215,2,3,15,10,74.9
2020-08-02 04:00:00,2020,215,3,7,15,7,74.9
2020-08-02 05:00:00,2020,215,4,7,15,6,74.9
2020-08-02 06:00:00,2020,215,5,7,15,11,74.9
2020-08-02 07:00:00,2020,215,6,10,15,17,74.9
2020-08-02 08:00:00,2020,215,7,10,15,14,74.9
2020-08-02 09:00:00,2020,215,8,10,15,19,74.9
2020-08-02 10:00:00,2020,215,9,27,15,22,74.9
2020-08-02 11:00:00,2020,215,10,27,15,21,74.9
2020-08-02 12:00:00,2020,215,11,27,15,12,74.9
2020-08-02 13:00:00,2020,215,12,33,15,-2,74.9
2020-08-02 14:00:00,2020,215,13,33,15,-14,74.9
2020-08-02 15:00:00,2020,215,14,33,15,-12,74.9
2020-08-02 16:00:00,2020,215,15,30,15,-14,74.9
2020-08-02 17:00:00,2020,215,16,30,15,-14,74.9
2020-08-02 18:00:00,2020,215,17,30,15,-7,74.9
2020-08-02 19:00:00,2020,215,18,20,15,0,74.9
2020-08-02 20:00:00,2020,215,19,20,15,3,74.9
2020-08-02 21:00:00,2020,215,20,20,15,9,74.9
2020-08-02 22:00:00,2020,215,21,30,15,-3,74.9
2020-08-02 23:00:00,2020,215,22,30,15,-8,74.9
2020-08-03 00:00:00,2020,215,23,30,15,-5,74.9
2020-08-03 01:00:00,2020,216,0,33,11,-2,74.8
2020-08-03 02:00:00,2020,216,1,33,11,-1,74.8
2020-08-03 03:00:00,2020,216,2,33,11,-2,74.8
2020-08-03 04:00:00,2020,216,3,33,11,-19,74.8
2020-08-03 05:00:00,2020,216,4,33,11,-17,74.8
2020-08-03 06:00:00,2020,216,5,33,11,-16,74.8
2020-08-03 07:00:00,2020,216,6,30,11,-22,74.8
2020-08-03 08:00:00,2020,216,7,30,11,-20,74.8
2020-08-03 09:00:00,2020,216,8,30,11,-28,74.8
2020-08-03 10:00:00,2020,216,9,27,11,-30,74.8
2020-08-03 11:00:00,2020,216,10,27,11,-18,74.8
2020-08-03 12:00:00,2020,216,11,27,11,-12,74.8
2020-08-03 13:00:00,2020,216,12,23,11,-7,74.8
2020-08-03 14:00:00,2020,216,13,23,11,-7,74.8
2020-08-03 15:00:00,2020,216,14,23,11,-9,74.8
2020-08-03 16:00:00,2020,216,15,33,11,-8,74.8
2020-08-03 17:00:00,2020,216,16,33,11,-3,74.8
2020-08-03 18:00:00,2020,216,17,33,11,-7,74.8
2020-08-03 19:00:00,2020,216,18,30,11,-13,74.8
2020-08-03 20:00:00,2020,216,19,30,11,-16,74.8
2020-08-03 21:00:00,2020,216,20,30,11,-16,74.8
2020-08-03 22:00:00,2020,216,21,33,11,-15,74.8
2020-08-03 23:00:00,2020,216,22,33,11,-21,74.8
2020-08-04 00:00:00,2020,216,23,33,11,-18,74.8
2020-08-04 01:00:00,2020,217,0,20,11,-14,75.1
2020-08-04 02:00:00,2020,217,1,20,11,-13,75.1
2020-08-04 03:00:00,2020,217,2,20,11,-18,75.1
2020-08-04 04:00:00,2020,217,3,33,11,-21,75.1
2020-08-04 05:00:00,2020,217,4,33,11,-20,75.1
2020-08-04 06:00:00,2020,217,5,33,11,-15,75.1
2020-08-04 07:00:00,2020,217,6,13,11,-13,75.1
2020-08-04 08:00:00,2020,217,7,13,11,-12,75.1
2020-08-04 09:00:00,2020,217,8,13,11,-11,75.1
2020-08-04 10:00:00,2020,217,9,17,11,-10,75.1
2020-08-04 11:00:00,2020,217,10,17,11,-9,75.1
2020-08-04 12:00:00,2020,217,11,17,11,-5,75.1
2020-08-04 13:00:00,2020,217,12,13,11,-5,75.1
2020-08-04 14:00:00,2020,217,13,13,11,-5,75.1
2020-08-04 15:00:00,2020,217,14,13,11,-5,75.1
2020-08-04 16:00:00,2020,217,15,13,11,-2,75.1
2020-08-04 17:00:00,2020,217,16,13,11,-1,75.1
2020-08-04 18:00:00,2020,217,17,13,11,-3,75.1
2020-08-04 19:00:00,2020,217,18,13,11,-3,75.1
2020-08-04 20:00:00,2020,217,19,13,11,-6,75.1
2020-08-04 21:00:00,2020,217,20,13,11,-10,75.1
2020-08-04 22:00:00,2020,217,21,17,11,-8,75.1
2020-08-04 23:00:00,2020,217,22,17,11,-11,75.1
2020-08-05 00:00:00,2020,217,23,17,11,-13,75.1
2020-08-05 01:00:00,2020,218,0,17,12,-11,75.6
2020-08-05 02:00:00,2020,218,1,17,12,-8,75.6
2020-08-05 03:00:00,2020,218,2,17,12,-11,75.6
2020-08-05 04:00:00,2020,218,3,13,12,-12,75.6
2020-08-05 05:00:00,2020,218,4,13,12,-11,75.6
2020-08-05 06:00:00,2020,218,5,13,12,-14,75.6
2020-08-05 07:00:00,2020,218,6,10,12,-14,75.6
2020-08-05 08:00:00,2020,218,7,10,12,-12,75.6
2020-08-05 09:00:00,2020,218,8,10,12,-11,75.6
2020-08-05 10:00:00,2020,218,9,7,12,-11,75.6
2020-08-05 11:00:00,2020,218,10,7,12,-11,75.6
2020-08-05 12:00:00,2020,218,11,7,12,-9,75.6
2020-08-05 13:00:00,2020,218,12,7,12,-7,75.6
2020-08-05 14:00:00,2020,218,13,7,12,-7,75.6
2020-08-05 15:00:00,2020,218,14,7,12,-4,75.6
2020-08-05 16:00:00,2020,218,15,10,12,-2,75.6
2020-08-05 17:00:00,2020,218,16,10,12,-3,75.6
2020-08-05 18:00:00,2020,218,17,10,12,-5,75.6
2020-08-05 19:00:00,2020,218,18,23,12,-4,75.6
2020-08-05 20:00:00,2020,218,19,23,12,-7,75.6
2020-08-05 21:00:00,2020,218,20,23,12,-5,75.6
2020-08-05 22:00:00,2020,218,21,13,12,-7,75.6
2020-08-05 23:00:00,2020,218,22,13,12,-12,75.6
2020-08-06 00:00:00,2020,218,23,13,12,-15,75.6
2020-08-06 01:00:00,2020,219,0,7,14,-16,75.1
2020-08-06 02:00:00,2020,219,1,7,14,-16,75.1
2020-08-06 03:00:00,2020,219,2,7,14,-13,75.1
2020-08-06 04:00:00,2020,219,3,13,14,-7,75.1
2020-08-06 05:00:00,2020,219,4,13,14,-2,75.1
2020-08-06 06:00:00,2020,219,5,13,14,1,75.1
2020-08-06 07:00:00,2020,219,6,3,14,1,75.1
2020-08-06 08:00:00,2020,219,7,3,14,0,75.1
2020-08-06 09:00:00,2020,219,8,3,14,-2,75.1
2020-08-06 10:00:00,2020,219,9,7,14,-5,75.1
2020-08-06 11:00:00,2020,219,10,7,14,-3,75.1
2020-08-06 12:00:00,2020,219,11,7,14,-1,75.1
2020-08-06 13:00:00,2020,219,12,17,14,-3,75.1
2020-08-06 14:00:00,2020,219,13,17,14,-8,75.1
2020-08-06 15:00:00,2020,219,14,17,14,-6,75.1
2020-08-06 16:00:00,2020,219,15,13,14,-6,75.1
2020-08-06 17:00:00,2020,219,16,13,14,-8,75.1
2020-08-06 18:00:00,2020,219,17,13,14,-9,75.1
2020-08-06 19:00:00,2020,219,18,7,14,-12,75.1
2020-08-06 20:00:00,2020,219,19,7,14,-10,75.1
2020-08-06 21:00:00,2020,219,20,7,14,-4,75.1
2020-08-06 22:00:00,2020,219,21,20,14,-7,75.1
2020-08-06 23:00:00,2020,219,22,20,14,-14,75.1
2020-08-07 00:00:00,2020,219,23,20,14,-16,75.1
2020-08-07 01:00:00,2020,220,0,17,17,-13,76.0
2020-08-07 02:00:00,2020,220,1,17,17,-14,76.0
2020-08-07 03:00:00,2020,220,2,17,17,-14,76.0
2020-08-07 04:00:00,2020,220,3,10,17,-13,76.0
2020-08-07 05:00:00,2020,220,4,10,17,-13,76.0
2020-08-07 06:00:00,2020,220,5,10,17,-11,76.0
2020-08-07 07:00:00,2020,220,6,0,17,-5,76.0
2020-08-07 08:00:00,2020,220,7,0,17,-3,76.0
2020-08-07 09:00:00,2020,220,8,0,17,-2,76.0
2020-08-07 10:00:00,2020,220,9,3,17,-2,76.0
2020-08-07 11:00:00,2020,220,10,3,17,-2,76.0
2020-08-07 12:00:00,2020,220,11,3,17,2,76.0
2020-08-07 13:00:00,2020,220,12,3,17,4,76.0
2020-08-07 14:00:00,2020,220,13,3,17,5,76.0
2020-08-07 15:00:00,2020,220,14,3,17,4,76.0
2020-08-07 16:00:00,2020,220,15,3,17,3,76.0
2020-08-07 17:00:00,2020,220,16,3,17,0,76.0
2020-08-07 18:00:00,2020,220,17,3,17,0,76.0
2020-08-07 19:00:00,2020,220,18,7,17,1,76.0
2020-08-07 20:00:00,2020,220,19,7,17,1,76.0
2020-08-07 21:00:00,2020,220,20,7,17,1,76.0
2020-08-07 22:00:00,2020,220,21,13,17,-2,76.0
2020-08-07 23:00:00,2020,220,22,13,17,-3,76.0
2020-08-08 00:00:00,2020,220,23,13,17,-1,76.0
2020-08-08 01:00:00,2020,221,0,20,12,-3,76.8
2020-08-08 02:00:00,2020,221,1,20,12,-6,76.8
2020-08-08 03:00:00,2020,221,2,20,12,-5,76.8
2020-08-08 04:00:00,2020,221,3,17,12,-4,76.8
2020-08-08 05:00:00,2020,221,4,17,12,-4,76.8
2020-08-08 06:00:00,2020,221,5,17,12,-5,76.8
2020-08-08 07:00:00,2020,221,6,13,12,-8,76.8
2020-08-08 08:00:00,2020,221,7,13,12,-10,76.8
2020-08-08 09:00:00,2020,221,8,13,12,-11,76.8
2020-08-08 10:00:00,2020,221,9,10,12,-7,76.8
2020-08-08 11:00:00,2020,221,10,10,12,-5,76.8
2020-08-08 12:00:00,2020,221,11,10,12,-4,76.8
2020-08-08 13:00:00,2020,221,12,13,12,-7,76.8
2020-08-08 14:00:00,2020,221,13,13,12,-8,76.8
2020-08-08 15:00:00,2020,221,14,13,12,-8,76.8
2020-08-08 16:00:00,2020,221,15,10,12,-10,76.8
2020-08-08 17:00:00,2020,221,16,10,12,-12,76.8
2020-08-08 18:00:00,2020,221,17,10,12,-12,76.8
2020-08-08 19:00:00,2020,221,18,7,12,-12,76.8
2020-08-08 20:00:00,2020,221,19,7,12,-10,76.8
2020-08-08 21:00:00,2020,221,20,7,12,-7,76.8
2020-08-08 22:00:00,2020,221,21,3,12,-2,76.8
2020-08-08 23:00:00,2020,221,22,3,12,0,76.8
2020-08-09 00:00:00,2020,221,23,3,12,-2,76.8
2020-08-09 01:00:00,2020,222,0,0,13,-4,76.0
2020-08-09 02:00:00,2020,222,1,0,13,-7,76.0
2020-08-09 03:00:00,2020,222,2,0,13,-8,76.0
2020-08-09 04:00:00,2020,222,3,3,13,-7,76.0
2020-08-09 05:00:00,2020,222,4,3,13,-7,76.0
2020-08-09 06:00:00,2020,222,5,3,13,-5,76.0
2020-08-09 07:00:00,2020,222,6,3,13,-2,76.0
2020-08-09 08:00:00,2020,222,7,3,13,-1,76.0
2020-08-09 09:00:00,2020,222,8,3,13,-2,76.0
2020-08-09 10:00:00,2020,222,9,7,13,-7,76.0
2020-08-09 11:00:00,2020,222,10,7,13,-8,76.0
2020-08-09 12:00:00,2020,222,11,7,13,-8,76.0
2020-08-09 13:00:00,2020,222,12,3,13,-8,76.0
2020-08-09 14:00:00,2020,222,13,3,13,-8,76.0
2020-08-09 15:00:00,2020,222,14,3,13,-6,76.0
2020-08-09 16:00:00,2020,222,15,3,13,-3,76.0
2020-08-09 17:00:00,2020,222,16,3,13,-4,76.0
2020-08-09 18:00:00,2020,222,17,3,13,-5,76.0
2020-08-09 19:00:00,2020,222,18,3,13,-4,76.0
2020-08-09 20:00:00,2020,222,19,3,13,0,76.0
2020-08-09 21:00:00,2020,222,20,3,13,4,76.0
2020-08-09 22:00:00,2020,222,21,7,13,5,76.0
2020-08-09 23:00:00,2020,222,22,7,13,5,76.0
2020-08-10 00:00:00,2020,222,23,7,13,6,76.0
2020-08-10 01:00:00,2020,223,0,3,13,4,76.2
2020-08-10 02:00:00,2020,223,1,3,13,4,76.2
2020-08-10 03:00:00,2020,223,2,3,13,6,76.2
2020-08-10 04:00:00,2020,223,3,3,13,5,76.2
2020-08-10 05:00:00,2020,223,4,3,13,2,76.2
2020-08-10 06:00:00,2020,223,5,3,13,0,76.2
2020-08-10 07:00:00,2020,223,6,3,13,-3,76.2
2020-08-10 08:00:00,2020,223,7,3,13,-5,76.2
2020-08-10 09:00:00,2020,223,8,3,13,-6,76.2
2020-08-10 10:00:00,2020,223,9,3,13,-7,76.2
2020-08-10 11:00:00,2020,223,10,3,13,-5,76.2
2020-08-10 12:00:00,2020,223,11,3,13,-4,76.2
2020-08-10 13:00:00,2020,223,12,0,13,-5,76.2
2020-08-10 14:00:00,2020,223,13,0,13,-4,76.2
2020-08-10 15:00:00,2020,223,14,0,13,0,76.2
2020-08-10 16:00:00,2020,223,15,7,13,1,76.2
2020-08-10 17:00:00,2020,223,16,7,13,-1,76.2
2020-08-10 18:00:00,2020,223,17,7,13,-1,76.2
2020-08-10 19:00:00,2020,223,18,3,13,0,76.2
2020-08-10 20:00:00,2020,223,19,3,13,3,76.2
2020-08-10 21:00:00,2020,223,20,3,13,4,76.2
2020-08-10 22:00:00,2020,223,21,7,13,3,76.2
2020-08-10 23:00:00,2020,223,22,7,13,1,76.2
2020-08-11 00:00:00,2020,223,23,7,13,-1,76.2
2020-08-11 01:00:00,2020,224,0,10,12,2,75.4
2020-08-11 02:00:00,2020,224,1,10,12,1,75.4
2020-08-11 03:00:00,2020,224,2,10,12,-3,75.4
2020-08-11 04:00:00,2020,224,3,7,12,-6,75.4
2020-08-11 05:00:00,2020,224,4,7,12,-6,75.4
2020-08-11 06:00:00,2020,224,5,7,12,-5,75.4
2020-08-11 07:00:00,2020,224,6,3,12,-4,75.4
2020-08-11 08:00:00,2020,224,7,3,12,-3,75.4
2020-08-11 09:00:00,2020,224,8,3,12,-4,75.4
2020-08-11 10:00:00,2020,224,9,3,12,-3,75.4
2020-08-11 11:00:00,2020,224,10,3,12,-2,75.4
2020-08-11 12:00:00,2020,224,11,3,12,-3,75.4
2020-08-11 13:00:00,2020,224,12,3,12,-3,75.4
2020-08-11 14:00:00,2020,224,13,3,12,0,75.4
2020-08-11 15:00:00,2020,224,14,3,12,1,75.4
2020-08-11 16:00:00,2020,224,15,0,12,2,75.4
2020-08-11 17:00:00,2020,224,16,0,12,1,75.4
2020-08-11 18:00:00,2020,224,17,0,12,1,75.4
2020-08-11 19:00:00,2020,224,18,0,12,5,75.4
2020-08-11 20:00:00,2020,224,19,0,12,6,75.4
2020-08-11 21:00:00,2020,224,20,0,12,5,75.4
2020-08-11 22:00:00,2020,224,21,3,12,4,75.4
2020-08-11 23:00:00,2020,224,22,3,12,7,75.4
2020-08-12 00:00:00,2020,224,23,3,12,10,75.4
2020-08-12 01:00:00,2020,225,0,3,17,10,75.1
2020-08-12 02:00:00,2020,225,1,3,17,10,75.1
2020-08-12 03:00:00,2020,225,2,3,17,12,75.1
2020-08-12 04:00:00,2020,225,3,13,17,9,75.1
2020-08-12 05:00:00,2020,225,4,13,17,5,75.1
2020-08-12 06:00:00,2020,225,5,13,17,3,75.1
2020-08-12 07:00:00,2020,225,6,10,17,2,75.1
2020-08-12 08:00:00,2020,225,7,10,17,2,75.1
2020-08-12 09:00:00,2020,225,8,10,17,0,75.1
2020-08-12 10:00:00,2020,225,9,7,17,1,75.1
2020-08-12 11:00:00,2020,225,10,7,17,2,75.1
2020-08-12 12:00:00,2020,225,11,7,17,3,75.1
2020-08-12 13:00:00,2020,225,12,10,17,3,75.1
2020-08-12 14:00:00,2020,225,13,10,17,6,75.1
2020-08-12 15:00:00,2020,225,14,10,17,7,75.1
2020-08-12 16:00:00,2020,225,15,7,17,8,75.1
2020-08-12 17:00:00,2020,225,16,7,17,8,75.1
2020-08-12 18:00:00,2020,225,17,7,17,7,75.1
2020-08-12 19:00:00,2020,225,18,7,17,5,75.1
2020-08-12 20:00:00,2020,225,19,7,17,4,75.1
2020-08-12 21:00:00,2020,225,20,7,17,6,75.1
2020-08-12 22:00:00,2020,225,21,3,17,7,75.1
2020-08-12 23:00:00,2020,225,22,3,17,5,75.1
2020-08-13 00:00:00,2020,225,23,3,17,2,75.1
2020-08-13 01:00:00,2020,226,0,17,10,1,74.2
2020-08-13 02:00:00,2020,226,1,17,10,0,74.2
2020-08-13 03:00:00,2020,226,2,17,10,0,74.2
2020-08-13 04:00:00,2020,226,3,7,10,-2,74.2
2020-08-13 05:00:00,2020,226,4,7,10,-1,74.2
2020-08-13 06:00:00,2020,226,5,7,10,2,74.2
2020-08-13 07:00:00,2020,226,6,3,10,4,74.2
2020-08-13 08:00:00,2020,226,7,3,10,7,74.2
2020-08-13 09:00:00,2020,226,8,3,10,6,74.2
2020-08-13 10:00:00,2020,226,9,3,10,5,74.2
2020-08-13 11:00:00,2020,226,10,3,10,4,74.2
2020-08-13 12:00:00,2020,226,11,3,10,2,74.2
2020-08-13 13:00:00,2020,226,12,13,10,2,74.2
2020-08-13 14:00:00,2020,226,13,13,10,2,74.2
2020-08-13 15:00:00,2020,226,14,13,10,3,74.2
2020-08-13 16:00:00,2020,226,15,3,10,2,74.2
2020-08-13 17:00:00,2020,226,16,3,10,3,74.2
2020-08-13 18:00:00,2020,226,17,3,10,1,74.2
2020-08-13 19:00:00,2020,226,18,3,10,-1,74.2
2020-08-13 20:00:00,2020,226,19,3,10,-1,74.2
2020-08-13 21:00:00,2020,226,20,3,10,2,74.2
2020-08-13 22:00:00,2020,226,21,13,10,-1,74.2
2020-08-13 23:00:00,2020,226,22,13,10,-5,74.2
2020-08-14 00:00:00,2020,226,23,13,10,-5,74.2
2020-08-14 01:00:00,2020,227,0,10,5,-2,72.6
2020-08-14 02:00:00,2020,227,1,10,5,1,72.6
2020-08-14 03:00:00,2020,227,2,10,5,6,72.6
2020-08-14 04:00:00,2020,227,3,17,5,4,72.6
2020-08-14 05:00:00,2020,227,4,17,5,1,72.6
2020-08-14 06:00:00,2020,227,5,17,5,3,72.6
2020-08-14 07:00:00,2020,227,6,3,5,3,72.6
2020-08-14 08:00:00,2020,227,7,3,5,2,72.6
2020-08-14 09:00:00,2020,227,8,3,5,3,72.6
2020-08-14 10:00:00,2020,227,9,3,5,6,72.6
2020-08-14 11:00:00,2020,227,10,3,5,8,72.6
2020-08-14 12:00:00,2020,227,11,3,5,7,72.6
2020-08-14 13:00:00,2020,227,12,7,5,5,72.6
2020-08-14 14:00:00,2020,227,13,7,5,6,72.6
2020-08-14 15:00:00,2020,227,14,7,5,6,72.6
2020-08-14 16:00:00,2020,227,15,3,5,7,72.6
2020-08-14 17:00:00,2020,227,16,3,5,6,72.6
2020-08-14 18:00:00,2020,227,17,3,5,3,72.6
2020-08-14 19:00:00,2020,227,18,7,5,-1,72.6
2020-08-14 20:00:00,2020,227,19,7,5,-5,72.6
2020-08-14 21:00:00,2020,227,20,7,5,-8,72.6
2020-08-14 22:00:00,2020,227,21,7,5,-9,72.6
2020-08-14 23:00:00,2020,227,22,7,5,-9,72.6
2020-08-15 00:00:00,2020,227,23,7,5,-11,72.6
2020-08-15 01:00:00,2020,228,0,0,0,-10,72.4
2020-08-15 02:00:00,2020,228,1,0,0,-5,72.4
2020-09-03 22:00:00,2020,247,21,17,0,-15,71.2
2020-09-03 23:00:00,2020,247,22,17,0,-17,71.2
2020-09-04 00:00:00,2020,247,23,17,0,-21,71.2
2020-09-04 01:00:00,2020,248,0,27,0,-22,70.8
2020-09-04 02:00:00,2020,248,1,27,0,-23,70.8
2020-09-04 03:00:00,2020,248,2,27,0,-19,70.8
2020-09-04 04:00:00,2020,248,3,13,0,-16,70.8
2020-09-04 05:00:00,2020,248,4,13,0,-14,70.8
2020-09-04 06:00:00,2020,248,5,13,0,-15,70.8
2020-09-04 07:00:00,2020,248,6,13,0,-18,70.8
2020-09-04 08:00:00,2020,248,7,13,0,-18,70.8
2020-09-04 09:00:00,2020,248,8,13,0,-15,70.8
2020-09-04 10:00:00,2020,248,9,20,0,-11,70.8
2020-09-04 11:00:00,2020,248,10,20,0,-18,70.8
2020-09-04 12:00:00,2020,248,11,20,0,-19,70.8
2020-09-04 13:00:00,2020,248,12,20,0,-18,70.8
2020-09-04 14:00:00,2020,248,13,20,0,-22,70.8
2020-09-04 15:00:00,2020,248,14,20,0,-21,70.8
2020-09-04 16:00:00,2020,248,15,17,0,-26,70.8
2020-09-04 17:00:00,2020,248,16,17,0,-27,70.8
2020-09-04 18:00:00,2020,248,17,17,0,-25,70.8
2020-09-04 19:00:00,2020,248,18,23,0,-22,70.8
2020-09-04 20:00:00,2020,248,19,23,0,-20,70.8
2020-09-04 21:00:00,2020,248,20,23,0,-24,70.8
2020-09-04 22:00:00,2020,248,21,3,0,-22,70.8
2020-09-04 23:00:00,2020,248,22,3,0,-21,70.8
2020-09-05 00:00:00,2020,248,23,3,0,-21,70.8
2020-09-05 01:00:00,2020,249,0,17,0,-21,70.3
2020-09-05 02:00:00,2020,249,1,17,0,-22,70.3
2020-09-05 03:00:00,2020,249,2,17,0,-23,70.3
2020-09-05 04:00:00,2020,249,3,13,0,-22,70.3
2020-09-05 05:00:00,2020,249,4,13,0,-19,70.3
2020-09-05 06:00:00,2020,249,5,13,0,-16,70.3
2020-09-05 07:00:00,2020,249,6,17,0,-15,70.3
2020-09-05 08:00:00,2020,249,7,17,0,-15,70.3
2020-09-05 09:00:00,2020,249,8,17,0,-21,70.3
2020-09-05 10:00:00,2020,249,9,20,0,-23,70.3
2020-09-05 11:00:00,2020,249,10,20,0,-22,70.3
2020-09-05 12:00:00,2020,249,11,20,0,-11,70.3
2020-09-05 13:00:00,2020,249,12,17,0,-7,70.3
2020-09-05 14:00:00,2020,249,13,17,0,-7,70.3
2020-09-05 15:00:00,2020,249,14,17,0,-7,70.3
2020-09-05 16:00:00,2020,249,15,3,0,-8,70.3
2020-09-05 17:00:00,2020,249,16,3,0,-9,70.3
2020-09-05 18:00:00,2020,249,17,3,0,-7,70.3
2020-09-05 19:00:00,2020,249,18,10,0,-8,70.3
2020-09-05 20:00:00,2020,249,19,10,0,-6,70.3
2020-09-05 21:00:00,2020,249,20,10,0,-6,70.3
2020-09-05 22:00:00,2020,249,21,10,0,-8,70.3
2020-09-05 23:00:00,2020,249,22,10,0,-9,70.3
2020-09-06 00:00:00,2020,249,23,10,0,-14,70.3
2020-09-06 01:00:00,2020,250,0,20,0,-18,70.5
2020-09-06 02:00:00,2020,250,1,20,0,-21,70.5
2020-09-06 03:00:00,2020,250,2,20,0,-16,70.5
2020-09-06 04:00:00,2020,250,3,10,0,-12,70.5
2020-09-06 05:00:00,2020,250,4,10,0,-10,70.5
2020-09-06 06:00:00,2020,250,5,10,0,-11,70.5
2020-09-06 07:00:00,2020,250,6,3,0,-8,70.5
2020-09-06 08:00:00,2020,250,7,3,0,-5,70.5
2020-09-06 09:00:00,2020,250,8,3,0,-7,70.5
2020-09-06 10:00:00,2020,250,9,10,0,-6,70.5
2020-09-06 11:00:00,2020,250,10,10,0,-6,70.5
2020-09-06 12:00:00,2020,250,11,10,0,-9,70.5
2020-09-06 13:00:00,2020,250,12,10,0,-9,70.5
2020-09-06 14:00:00,2020,250,13,10,0,-7,70.5
2020-09-06 15:00:00,2020,250,14,10,0,-6,70.5
2020-09-06 16:00:00,2020,250,15,3,0,-7,70.5
2020-09-06 17:00:00,2020,250,16,3,0,-7,70.5
2020-09-06 18:00:00,2020,250,17,3,0,-6,70.5
2020-09-06 19:00:00,2020,250,18,7,0,-5,70.5
2020-09-06 20:00:00,2020,250,19,7,0,-6,70.5
2020-09-06 21:00:00,2020,250,20,7,0,-9,70.5
2020-09-06 22:00:00,2020,250,21,17,0,-15,70.5
2020-09-06 23:00:00,2020,250,22,17,0,-20,70.5
2020-09-07 00:00:00,2020,250,23,17,0,-21,70.5
2020-09-07 01:00:00,2020,251,0,10,0,-21,71.3
2020-09-07 02:00:00,2020,251,1,10,0,-16,71.3
2020-09-07 03:00:00,2020,251,2,10,0,-13,71.3
2020-09-07 04:00:00,2020,251,3,13,0,-11,71.3
2020-09-07 05:00:00,2020,251,4,13,0,-14,71.3
2020-09-07 06:00:00,2020,251,5,13,0,-17,71.3
2020-09-07 07:00:00,2020,251,6,13,0,-14,71.3
2020-09-07 08:00:00,2020,251,7,13,0,-10,71.3
2020-09-07 09:00:00,2020,251,8,13,0,-11,71.3
2020-09-07 10:00:00,2020,251,9,7,0,-11,71.3
2020-09-07 11:00:00,2020,251,10,7,0,-13,71.3
2020-09-07 12:00:00,2020,251,11,7,0,-14,71.3
2020-09-07 13:00:00,2020,251,12,7,0,-15,71.3
2020-09-07 14:00:00,2020,251,13,7,0,-12,71.3
2020-09-07 15:00:00,2020,251,14,7,0,-12,71.3
2020-09-07 16:00:00,2020,251,15,10,0,-10,71.3
2020-09-07 17:00:00,2020,251,16,10,0,-13,71.3
2020-09-07 18:00:00,2020,251,17,10,0,-12,71.3
2020-09-07 19:00:00,2020,251,18,3,0,-9,71.3
2020-09-07 20:00:00,2020,251,19,3,0,-8,71.3
2020-09-07 21:00:00,2020,251,20,3,0,-10,71.3
2020-09-07 22:00:00,2020,251,21,0,0,-14,71.3
2020-09-07 23:00:00,2020,251,22,0,0,-16,71.3
2020-09-08 00:00:00,2020,251,23,0,0,-16,71.3
2020-09-08 01:00:00,2020,252,0,7,0,-12,70.9
2020-09-08 02:00:00,2020,252,1,7,0,-12,70.9
2020-09-08 03:00:00,2020,252,2,7,0,-13,70.9
2020-09-08 04:00:00,2020,252,3,3,0,-12,70.9
2020-09-08 05:00:00,2020,252,4,3,0,-12,70.9
2020-09-08 06:00:00,2020,252,5,3,0,-12,70.9
2020-09-08 07:00:00,2020,252,6,10,0,-9,70.9
2020-09-08 08:00:00,2020,252,7,10,0,-6,70.9
2020-09-08 09:00:00,2020,252,8,10,0,-6,70.9
2020-09-08 10:00:00,2020,252,9,10,0,-1,70.9
2020-09-08 11:00:00,2020,252,10,10,0,2,70.9
2020-09-08 12:00:00,2020,252,11,10,0,1,70.9
2020-09-08 13:00:00,2020,252,12,7,0,2,70.9
2020-09-08 14:00:00,2020,252,13,7,0,3,70.9
2020-09-08 15:00:00,2020,252,14,7,0,-1,70.9
2020-09-08 16:00:00,2020,252,15,13,0,-6,70.9
2020-09-08 17:00:00,2020,252,16,13,0,-7,70.9
2020-09-08 18:00:00,2020,252,17,13,0,-9,70.9
2020-09-08 19:00:00,2020,252,18,10,0,-7,70.9
2020-09-08 20:00:00,2020,252,19,10,0,-5,70.9
2020-09-08 21:00:00,2020,252,20,10,0,-3,70.9
2020-09-08 22:00:00,2020,252,21,0,0,-2,70.9
2020-09-08 23:00:00,2020,252,22,0,0,-2,70.9
2020-09-09 00:00:00,2020,252,23,0,0,-2,70.9
2020-09-09 01:00:00,2020,253,0,7,0,-3,70.7
2020-09-09 02:00:00,2020,253,1,7,0,-4,70.7
2020-09-09 03:00:00,2020,253,2,7,0,-4,70.7
2020-09-09 04:00:00,2020,253,3,0,0,-5,70.7
2020-09-09 05:00:00,2020,253,4,0,0,-5,70.7
2020-09-09 06:00:00,2020,253,5,0,0,-6,70.7
2020-09-09 07:00:00,2020,253,6,0,0,-2,70.7
2020-09-09 08:00:00,2020,253,7,0,0,0,70.7
2020-09-09 09:00:00,2020,253,8,0,0,0,70.7
2020-09-09 10:00:00,2020,253,9,0,0,1,70.7
2020-09-09 11:00:00,2020,253,10,0,0,2,70.7
2020-09-09 12:00:00,2020,253,11,0,0,1,70.7
2020-09-09 13:00:00,2020,253,12,0,0,1,70.7
2020-09-09 14:00:00,2020,253,13,0,0,0,70.7
2020-09-09 15:00:00,2020,253,14,0,0,-1,70.7
2020-09-09 16:00:00,2020,253,15,3,0,-2,70.7
2020-09-09 17:00:00,2020,253,16,3,0,-1,70.7
2020-09-09 18:00:00,2020,253,17,3,0,0,70.7
2020-09-09 19:00:00,2020,253,18,0,0,0,70.7
2020-09-09 20:00:00,2020,253,19,0,0,1,70.7
2020-09-09 21:00:00,2020,253,20,0,0,0,70.7
2020-09-09 22:00:00,2020,253,21,0,0,-1,70.7
2020-09-09 23:00:00,2020,253,22,0,0,1,70.7
2020-09-10 00:00:00,2020,253,23,0,0,1,70.7
2020-09-10 01:00:00,2020,254,0,0,0,0,70.2
2020-09-10 02:00:00,2020,254,1,0,0,0,70.2
2020-09-10 03:00:00,2020,254,2,0,0,0,70.2
2020-09-10 04:00:00,2020,254,3,0,0,-1,70.2
2020-09-10 05:00:00,2020,254,4,0,0,-1,70.2
2020-09-10 06:00:00,2020,254,5,0,0,-2,70.2
2020-09-10 07:00:00,2020,254,6,0,0,-3,70.2
2020-09-10 08:00:00,2020,254,7,0,0,-1,70.2
2020-09-10 09:00:00,2020,254,8,0,0,1,70.2
2020-09-10 10:00:00,2020,254,9,3,0,3,70.2
2020-09-10 11:00:00,2020,254,10,3,0,-1,70.2
2020-09-10 12:00:00,2020,254,11,3,0,1,70.2
2020-09-10 13:00:00,2020,254,12,3,0,2,70.2
2020-09-10 14:00:00,2020,254,13,3,0,4,70.2
2020-09-10 15:00:00,2020,254,14,3,0,3,70.2
2020-09-10 16:00:00,2020,254,15,3,0,2,70.2
2020-09-10 17:00:00,2020,254,16,3,0,2,70.2
2020-09-10 18:00:00,2020,254,17,3,0,4,70.2
2020-09-10 19:00:00,2020,254,18,10,0,3,70.2
2020-09-10 20:00:00,2020,254,19,10,0,1,70.2
2020-09-10 21:00:00,2020,254,20,10,0,1,70.2
2020-09-10 22:00:00,2020,254,21,3,0,4,70.2
2020-09-10 23:00:00,2020,254,22,3,0,4,70.2
2020-09-11 00:00:00,2020,254,23,3,0,2,70.2
2020-09-11 01:00:00,2020,255,0,0,0,2,69.6
2020-09-11 02:00:00,2020,255,1,0,0,4,69.6
2020-09-11 03:00:00,2020,255,2,0,0,3,69.6
2020-09-11 04:00:00,2020,255,3,0,0,4,69.6
2020-09-11 05:00:00,2020,255,4,0,0,2,69.6
2020-09-11 06:00:00,2020,255,5,0,0,2,69.6
2020-09-11 07:00:00,2020,255,6,3,0,2,69.6
2020-09-11 08:00:00,2020,255,7,3,0,2,69.6
2020-09-11 09:00:00,2020,255,8,3,0,-1,69.6
2020-09-11 10:00:00,2020,255,9,3,0,-2,69.6
2020-09-11 11:00:00,2020,255,10,3,0,-1,69.6
2020-09-11 12:00:00,2020,255,11,3,0,-2,69.6
2020-09-11 13:00:00,2020,255,12,0,0,-2,69.6
2020-09-11 14:00:00,2020,255,13,0,0,-1,69.6
2020-09-11 15:00:00,2020,255,14,0,0,-1,69.6
2020-09-11 16:00:00,2020,255,15,7,0,-1,69.6
2020-09-11 17:00:00,2020,255,16,7,0,0,69.6
2020-09-11 18:00:00,2020,255,17,7,0,-2,69.6
2020-09-11 19:00:00,2020,255,18,10,0,0,69.6
2020-09-11 20:00:00,2020,255,19,10,0,-1,69.6
2020-09-11 21:00:00,2020,255,20,10,0,-2,69.6
2020-09-11 22:00:00,2020,255,21,10,0,-6,69.6
2020-09-11 23:00:00,2020,255,22,10,0,-10,69.6
2020-09-12 00:00:00,2020,255,23,10,0,-11,69.6
2020-09-12 01:00:00,2020,256,0,13,0,-10,70.2
2020-09-12 02:00:00,2020,256,1,13,0,-8,70.2
2020-09-12 03:00:00,2020,256,2,13,0,-7,70.2
2020-09-12 04:00:00,2020,256,3,13,0,-5,70.2
2020-09-12 05:00:00,2020,256,4,13,0,-5,70.2
2020-09-12 06:00:00,2020,256,5,13,0,-8,70.2
2020-09-12 07:00:00,2020,256,6,20,0,-8,70.2
2020-09-12 08:00:00,2020,256,7,20,0,-7,70.2
2020-09-12 09:00:00,2020,256,8,20,0,-8,70.2
2020-09-12 10:00:00,2020,256,9,13,0,-8,70.2
2020-09-12 11:00:00,2020,256,10,13,0,-2,70.2
2020-09-12 12:00:00,2020,256,11,13,0,1,70.2
2020-09-12 13:00:00,2020,256,12,3,0,1,70.2
2020-09-12 14:00:00,2020,256,13,3,0,1,70.2
2020-09-12 15:00:00,2020,256,14,3,0,-2,70.2
2020-09-12 16:00:00,2020,256,15,7,0,-5,70.2
2020-09-12 17:00:00,2020,256,16,7,0,-4,70.2
2020-09-12 18:00:00,2020,256,17,7,0,-2,70.2
2020-09-12 19:00:00,2020,256,18,13,0,0,70.2
2020-09-12 20:00:00,2020,256,19,13,0,-1,70.2
2020-09-12 21:00:00,2020,256,20,13,0,-3,70.2
2020-09-12 22:00:00,2020,256,21,10,0,-5,70.2
2020-09-12 23:00:00,2020,256,22,10,0,-8,70.2
2020-09-13 00:00:00,2020,256,23,10,0,-9,70.2
2020-09-13 01:00:00,2020,257,0,10,0,-7,70.6
2020-09-13 02:00:00,2020,257,1,10,0,-8,70.6
2020-09-13 03:00:00,2020,257,2,10,0,-11,70.6
2020-09-13 04:00:00,2020,257,3,13,0,-11,70.6
2020-09-13 05:00:00,2020,257,4,13,0,-6,70.6
2020-09-13 06:00:00,2020,257,5,13,0,-5,70.6
2020-09-13 07:00:00,2020,257,6,13,0,-6,70.6
2020-09-13 08:00:00,2020,257,7,13,0,-9,70.6
2020-09-13 09:00:00,2020,257,8,13,0,-8,70.6
2020-09-13 10:00:00,2020,257,9,3,0,-6,70.6
2020-09-13 11:00:00,2020,257,10,3,0,-3,70.6
2020-09-13 12:00:00,2020,257,11,3,0,-2,70.6
2020-09-13 13:00:00,2020,257,12,13,0,0,70.6
2020-09-13 14:00:00,2020,257,13,13,0,2,70.6
2020-09-13 15:00:00,2020,257,14,13,0,0,70.6
2020-09-13 16:00:00,2020,257,15,17,0,1,70.6
2020-09-13 17:00:00,2020,257,16,17,0,1,70.6
2020-09-13 18:00:00,2020,257,17,17,0,9,70.6
2020-09-13 19:00:00,2020,257,18,13,0,8,70.6
2020-09-13 20:00:00,2020,257,19,13,0,8,70.6
2020-09-13 21:00:00,2020,257,20,13,0,12,70.6
2020-09-13 22:00:00,2020,257,21,30,0,8,70.6
2020-09-13 23:00:00,2020,257,22,30,0,8,70.6
2020-09-14 00:00:00,2020,257,23,30,0,9,70.6
2020-09-14 01:00:00,2020,258,0,33,2,4,69.7
2020-09-14 02:00:00,2020,258,1,33,2,-10,69.7
2020-09-14 03:00:00,2020,258,2,33,2,-19,69.7
2020-09-14 04:00:00,2020,258,3,33,2,-24,69.7
2020-09-14 05:00:00,2020,258,4,33,2,-35,69.7
2020-09-14 06:00:00,2020,258,5,33,2,-34,69.7
2020-09-14 07:00:00,2020,258,6,23,2,-29,69.7
2020-09-14 08:00:00,2020,258,7,23,2,-26,69.7
2020-09-14 09:00:00,2020,258,8,23,2,-29,69.7
2020-09-14 10:00:00,2020,258,9,27,2,-15,69.7
2020-09-14 11:00:00,2020,258,10,27,2,-10,69.7
2020-09-14 12:00:00,2020,258,11,27,2,-6,69.7
2020-09-14 13:00:00,2020,258,12,30,2,-12,69.7
2020-09-14 14:00:00,2020,258,13,30,2,-13,69.7
2020-09-14 15:00:00,2020,258,14,30,2,-10,69.7
2020-09-14 16:00:00,2020,258,15,10,2,-9,69.7
2020-09-14 17:00:00,2020,258,16,10,2,-8,69.7
2020-09-14 18:00:00,2020,258,17,10,2,-6,69.7
2020-09-14 19:00:00,2020,258,18,7,2,-7,69.7
2020-09-14 20:00:00,2020,258,19,7,2,-8,69.7
2020-09-14 21:00:00,2020,258,20,7,2,-10,69.7
2020-09-14 22:00:00,2020,258,21,20,2,-12,69.7
2020-09-14 23:00:00,2020,258,22,20,2,-14,69.7
2020-09-15 00:00:00,2020,258,23,20,2,-17,69.7
2020-09-15 01:00:00,2020,259,0,23,0,-17,69.6
2020-09-15 02:00:00,2020,259,1,23,0,-18,69.6
2020-09-15 03:00:00,2020,259,2,23,0,-16,69.6
2020-09-15 04:00:00,2020,259,3,20,0,-17,69.6
2020-09-17 00:00:00,2020,260,23,3,0,-15,70.2


The following code is an adaptation of the excellent answer by @Muhammed Yunus.
This updated version organizes the management of space weather data into a Class called SpaceWeather.
A more detailed discussion of the changes is at my blog Visualizing Space Weather Data: From Procedural to Object-Oriented Approach.
Key enhancements include:

Refactoring: The SpaceWeather class bundles related data and methods. The load_and_clean_data method loads and cleans data, and plot_data manages plotting.

Modularity: Separate methods are for different plot types (imshow, pcolormesh, contourf, plot_surface).

Type Hints: All function parameters and return types employ type hints.

Efficiency: plot_type == 'plot_surface' in this answer resulted in an unused figure, which is avoided in plot_surface.

Code Comments and Docstrings: Functionality is described by detailed comments and docstrings.

PEP8 Compliance: The code follows the PEP8 style guide.



Tested with:

python version: 3.12.0
pandas version: 2.2.1
numpy version: 1.26.4
matplotlib version: 3.8.1



import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from typing import Dict, Union
import matplotlib.figure
import matplotlib.axes


class SpaceWeather:
    def __init__(self, file_path: str):
        """
        Initialize the SpaceWeather class.

        Parameters:
        file_path (str): The path to the CSV file containing the data.
        """
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.df = None
        self.img_data = None
        self.labels = None
        self.dates = None

    def load_and_clean_data(self):
        """
        Load and clean the space weather data.
        The code for which is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/78294905/7758804
        """
        # Load the necessary columns, parse dates, skip header, and rename columns
        self.df = pd.read_csv(
            self.file_path,
            parse_dates=[0],
            skiprows=1,
            usecols=[0, 4, 6],
            names=["date", "kp", "dst"],
            header=0,
        )

        # Extract day of year and hour into new columns
        self.df["day_of_year"] = self.df["date"].dt.day_of_year  # new columns
        self.df["hour"] = self.df["date"].dt.hour

        # Add event column
        self.df["event"] = ""
        self.df.loc[(self.df.kp > 40) | (self.df.dst < -30), "event"] = "S"
        self.df.loc[self.df.date == pd.Timestamp("2020/09/01 01:00"), "event"] = "E"

        # Create image data
        self.img_data = self.df.pivot_table(
            index="hour", columns="day_of_year", values="dst"
        ).values
        # Create labels to be used as annotations
        self.labels = self.df.pivot(
            index="hour", columns="day_of_year", values="event"
        ).values
        # Create date range for x-axis
        self.dates = pd.date_range(
            start=self.df.date.min(),
            end=self.df.date.max() + pd.offsets.Day(),
            freq="D",
            inclusive="both",
        )

    def plot_data(self, plot_type: str = "imshow"):
        """
        Plot the space weather data.
        The code for plotting is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/78294536/7758804

        Parameters:
        plot_type (str): The type of plot to create. Options are 'imshow', 'pcolormesh', 'contourf', 'plot_surface'.
        """
        common_params: Dict[str, Union[int, str]] = dict(
            vmin=-40, vmax=20, cmap="jet_r"
        )

        # Create meshgrid for non-imshow plots
        if plot_type != "imshow":
            x, y = np.meshgrid(
                mdates.date2num(self.dates), range(self.img_data.shape[0])
            )

        # Plot data based on a plot type
        if plot_type == "imshow":
            self.plot_imshow(common_params)
        elif plot_type == "pcolormesh":
            self.plot_pcolormesh(x, y, common_params)
        elif plot_type == "contourf":
            self.plot_contourf(x, y, common_params)
        elif plot_type == "plot_surface":
            self.plot_surface(x, y, common_params)

    def plot_imshow(self, common_params: Dict[str, Union[int, str]]):
        """
        Plot the space weather data using imshow.

        Parameters:
        common_params (Dict[str, Union[int, str]]): Common parameters for the plot.
        """
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 3))
        im = ax.imshow(
            self.img_data,
            interpolation="none",
            aspect="auto",
            origin="lower",
            extent=(
                mdates.date2num(self.dates[0] - pd.offsets.Hour(12)),
                mdates.date2num(self.dates[-1] + pd.offsets.Hour(12)),
                float(self.df["hour"].min()),
                float(self.df["hour"].max()),
            ),
            **common_params,
        )
        self.format_plot(f, im, ax, "imshow")

    def plot_pcolormesh(self, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, common_params: Dict[str, Union[int, str]]):
        """
        Plot the space weather data using pcolormesh.

        Parameters:
        x (np.ndarray): The X coordinates of the meshgrid.
        y (np.ndarray): The Y coordinates of the meshgrid.
        common_params (Dict[str, Union[int, str]]): Common parameters for the plot.
        """
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 3))
        im = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, self.img_data, **common_params)
        self.format_plot(f, im, ax, "pcolormesh")

    def plot_contourf(self, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, common_params: Dict[str, Union[int, str]]):
        """
        Plot the space weather data using contourf.

        Parameters:
        x (np.ndarray): The X coordinates of the meshgrid.
        y (np.ndarray): The Y coordinates of the meshgrid.
        common_params (Dict[str, Union[int, str]]): Common parameters for the plot.
        """
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 3))
        im = ax.contourf(x, y, self.img_data, levels=10, **common_params)
        self.format_plot(f, im, ax, "contourf")

    def plot_surface(self, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, common_params: Dict[str, Union[int, str]]):
        """
        Plot the space weather data using plot_surface.

        Parameters:
        x (np.ndarray): The X coordinates of the meshgrid.
        y (np.ndarray): The Y coordinates of the meshgrid.
        common_params (Dict[str, Union[int, str]]): Common parameters for the plot.
        """
        f = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 11))
        ax = f.add_subplot(projection="3d", proj_type="persp", focal_length=0.2)

        ax.view_init(azim=79, elev=25)
        ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=(3, 2, 1.5), zoom=0.95)

        im = ax.plot_surface(x, y, self.img_data, **common_params)
        ax.contourf(
            x,
            y,
            self.img_data,
            levels=10,
            zdir="z",
            offset=-35,
            alpha=0.3,
            **common_params,
        )
        ax.contour(
            x,
            y,
            self.img_data,
            levels=8,
            zdir="z",
            offset=24,
            alpha=0.5,
            linewidths=3,
            **common_params,
        )
        ax.set_zlabel("Dst")
        ax.invert_xaxis()  # Orders the dates from left to right
        ax.invert_yaxis()  # Orders the hours from front to back
        self.format_plot(f, im, ax, "plot_surface")

    def format_plot(self, f: matplotlib.figure.Figure, im: matplotlib.image.AxesImage, ax: matplotlib.axes.Axes,
                    plot_type: str):
        """
        Format the plot.

        Parameters:
        f (matplotlib.figure.Figure): The figure.
        im (matplotlib.image.AxesImage): The image.
        ax (matplotlib.axes.Axes): The axes.
        plot_type (str): The type of plot.
        """
        # Add labels
        for (row, col), label in np.ndenumerate(self.labels):
            if plot_type == "plot_surface":
                break  # skip labels on 3d plot for simplicity

            if type(label) is not str:
                continue
            ax.text(
                self.dates[col] - pd.offsets.Hour(6),
                row,
                label,
                fontsize=9,
                fontweight="bold",
            )

        # Format x-axis with dates
        ax.set_xticks(self.dates)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt="%b %d"))
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=5))  # Tick every 5 days
        ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)

        # Format y axis
        ax.set_yticks([0, 6, 12, 18, 23])
        ax.set_ylabel("UT")

        # Add colorbar
        aspect, fraction = (10, 0.15) if plot_type != "plot_surface" else (5, 0.05)
        f.colorbar(im, aspect=aspect, fraction=fraction, pad=0.01, label="nT")

        # Add title
        ax.set_title(f"Dst\n(plot type: {plot_type})", fontweight="bold")

        # Adjust layout
        plt.tight_layout()

        # Save the plot
        plt.savefig(f"{plot_type}_plot.png", dpi=300)

        # Show the plot
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sw = SpaceWeather("spaceWeather.csv")
    sw.load_and_clean_data()

    for plot_type in ["imshow", "pcolormesh", "contourf", "plot_surface"]:
        print(f"Plotting with plot type: {plot_type}")
        sw.plot_data(plot_type)


Examples below for the various methods you've asked about (including a 3D plot for interest).
imshow:

pcolormesh:

contourf:

plot_surface (including contour projections):

Regarding the comment about configuring the tick frequency; I have updated my answer to show how you can configure fewer ticks, such as every 5 days. I set the axis tick locator to a matplotlib.dates.DayLocator() object with an interval= of 5 days. You can also configure it to tick the Nth day of each month using its bymonthday=N parameter. There are other types of locators available as well (WeekdayLocator(), HourLocator(), etc).

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, dates as mdates
import numpy as np

#
#Load and format data
#
df = pd.read_csv(
    'spaceWeather.csv',
    parse_dates=[0],
    skiprows=1,       #skip erroneous data in second row
    usecols=[0, 4, 6],
    names=['date', 'kp', 'dst'],
    header=0         #there is an existing header being replaced
).sort_values(by='date')

#New columns for day_of_year, hour, and event
df['day_of_year'] = df['date'].dt.day_of_year
df['hour'] = df['date'].dt.hour

df['event'] = ''
df.loc[(df.kp > 40) | (df.dst < -30), 'event'] = 'S'
df.loc[df.date == pd.Timestamp('2020/09/01 01:00'), 'event'] = 'E'

#Pivot into a table arranged (hours x day of year) where the values are dst or event
img_data = df.pivot_table(index='hour', columns='day_of_year', values='dst').values
labels = df.pivot(index='hour', columns='day_of_year', values='event').values
dates = pd.date_range(
    start=df.date.min(),
    end=df.date.max() + pd.offsets.Day(),
    freq='D', inclusive='both'
)

#
#Plot
#

#Select a plot type
plot_type = 'imshow'
plot_type = 'contourf'
plot_type = 'plot_surface'
plot_type = 'pcolormesh'

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 3))

common_params = dict(vmin=-40, vmax=20, cmap='jet_r')

if plot_type != 'imshow':
    #Everything here apart from imshow uses pre-defined regular grids X, Y
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(mdates.date2num(dates), range(img_data.shape[0]))

if plot_type == 'imshow':
    im = ax.imshow(
        img_data,
        interpolation='none',
        aspect='auto',
        origin='lower',
        extent=[
            dates[0] - pd.offsets.Hour(12),
            dates[-1] + pd.offsets.Hour(12),
            df['hour'].min(),
            df['hour'].max()
        ],
        **common_params
    )
elif plot_type == 'pcolormesh':
    im = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, img_data, **common_params)
elif plot_type == 'contourf':
    im = ax.contourf(X, Y, img_data, levels=10, **common_params)
elif plot_type == 'plot_surface':    
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 11))
    ax = f.add_subplot(projection='3d', proj_type='persp', focal_length=0.2)
    
    ax.view_init(azim=79, elev=25)
    ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=(3, 2, 1.5), zoom=0.95)

    im = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, img_data, **common_params)
    ax.contourf(X, Y, img_data, levels=10, zdir='z', offset=-35, alpha=0.3, **common_params)
    ax.contour(X, Y, img_data, levels=8, zdir='z', offset=24, alpha=0.5, linewidths=3, **common_params)
    ax.set_zlabel('Dst')

#Add labels
for (row, col), label in np.ndenumerate(labels):
    if plot_type == 'plot_surface': break #skip labels on 3d plot for simplicity
    
    if type(label) is not str: continue
    ax.text(dates[col] - pd.offsets.Hour(6), row, label, fontsize=9, fontweight='bold')

#Format x axis with dates:
ax.set_xticks(dates)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%b %d'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=5)) #Tick every 5 days
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

#Format y axis
ax.set_yticks([0, 6, 12, 18, 23])
ax.set_ylabel('UT')

#Add colorbar
aspect, fraction = (10, 0.15) if plot_type != 'plot_surface' else (5, 0.05)
f.colorbar(im, aspect=aspect, fraction=fraction, pad=0.01, label='nT')

#Title
ax.set_title(f'Dst\n(plot type: {plot_type})', fontweight='bold')

See the wiki contribution to this question by @TrentonMcKinney for a neatly encapsulated implementation called SpaceWeather.

The Python script performs the following operations:

Imports necessary libraries: pandas, seaborn, and matplotlib.

Reads a CSV file named spaceWeather.csv from a specified path, skipping the first row of several columns.

Creates new columns 'Date' and 'Hour' in the dataframe by extracting the date and hour from the 'Unnamed: 0' column.

Adds a new column 'Weather' to the dataframe. If the 'kp' value is greater than 40 or the 'dst' value is less than -30, the 'Weather' is labeled as 'Storm'. Otherwise, it remains an empty string.

Removes the row with the date '2020-09-17' as it only has one observation.

Creates two pivot tables: one for the 'Weather' annotations and another for the 'dst' values, both indexed by 'Date' and 'Hour'.

To switch the axes of your heatmap, you can interchange the column names passed to index and columns in the pivot function for both annot and dst.


Plots a heatmap using seaborn, representing the 'dst' values. The 'Weather' annotations are used as labels on the heatmap.

Use plt.text to annotate the figure in a spot specified with x and y.

Saves the plot as a PNG file named 'spaceWeather.png' and then displays it.



Implemented with Python 3.12.0, Pandas 2.2.1, Seaborn 0.13.2, Matplotlib 3.8.1

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# There's an issue with the first row of several columns, so they're being skipped
df = pd.read_csv('spaceWeather.csv', parse_dates=[0], usecols=[0, 4, 6])

# Create a date column
df['Date'] = df['Unnamed: 0'].dt.date

# Create an hour column
df['Hour'] = df['Unnamed: 0'].dt.hour

# Add a column labeled Weather based on the value of kp and dst
# If kp is greater than 40 or dst is less than -30, the weather is a storm, otherwise the label is ''
df['Weather'] = ''
df.loc[(df['kp'] > 40) | (df['dst'] < -30), 'Weather'] = 'Storm'

# There's only one observation for 2020-09-17, so we'll drop it
df = df[df['Date'] != pd.Timestamp('2020-09-17').date()]

# Create a pivot table for the annotations in the 'Weather' column
annot = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Hour', values='Weather')

# Create a pivot table for the dst values
dst = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Hour', values='dst')

# Plot the seaborn heatmap for dst, with annot for annotations
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
ax = sns.heatmap(data=dst, annot=annot, fmt='', cmap='coolwarm', cbar_kws={'label': 'dst'})
ax.set_title('Space Weather')

# On 2020-09-01 add a single annotation near the date, with "Earthquake"
plt.text(0.07, 0.335, 'Earthquake', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=15)

plt.savefig('spaceWeather.png')
plt.show()


